# Laravel 5.2 - ReflectionException Class laravel-fullcalendar does not exist

Tags: laravel, fullcalendar, laravel-facade

I am using the Fullcalendar package for Laravel 5.

I am experiencing this error:

```
ReflectionException in Container.php line 734:
Class laravel-fullcalendar does not exist
```

I have the Service Provider and the Facade in app.php.

This is my controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Lesson;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use MaddHatter\LaravelFullcalendar\Facades\Calendar;

class CalendarController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $calendar_events = Lesson::all();
        return view('admin.calendar', ['calendar' => Calendar::addEvent($calendar_events)]);     
    }
}
```

I don't understand the reason of this error. 
I tried to use `\Calendar` without the "use" line, `MaddHatter\LaravelFullcalendar\Facades\Calendar::addEvent()` directly and I tried several times `composer dump-autoload`.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that I started having the same problem with all the new installed packages.
I resolved in this way:

1. `composer dump-autoload`
2. `php artisan cache:clear`
3. `php artisan config:clear`